# Trouble installing Open Office

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I'm trying to install OpenOffice on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

1. I uninstalled LibreOffice per the command line

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice-core
   ```
2. I originally downloaded the `Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.3_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz`, unzipped it on the Desktop and manually went through, double clicking on every *.deb package and letting the software center install it. This did not work. There was no item in the menu for OpenOffice and there was nothing when I did a search.
3. I then tried to install the DEBs from the command line:

   ```
   cd en-US/
   cd DEBS/
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   This did not work either
4. I then tried another removal of LibreOffice just to be sure:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge libreoffice
   ```

   And still there was nothing in the menu even when searching. A command line command of "soffice" only yielded:

   ```
   /usr/bin/soffice: 175: exec: /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/oosplash: not found
   ```
5. I then tried:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install openoffice
   sudo apt-get install libxrandr2:i386 libxinerama1:i386
   sudo chmod a+rx /opt/openoffice4/share/uno_packages/cache
   ```

   Still received the same results as before.
6. I then tried the following:

   ```
   cd desktop-integration/
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   Still, same results as above.
7. I then downloaded the newest JRE 64 bit and unpacked/installed in the `/usr/java` directory.

   ```
   sudo tar zxvf jre-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```

   And I still don't have a working OpenOffice.

Is this a wild goose chase? Does OpenOffice simply not work on Ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the GDebi package manager to install `*.deb` packages. Install it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Then, to install a package, right click your `*.deb` package → *Open with* → *GDebi Package Installer* → *Install package*.

I like this because you can see detailed dependencies that you needed in status.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried to install the main *.deb for OpenOffice through gdebi and it said it was already installed, but I clicked on the reinstallation option. Nothing wrong. Successfully installed. So then I tried to install the menus *.deb through gdebi. This time it came up with an error "dpkg: error processing archive /.../openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.3-9783_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1"......................

Comment: So I ran "sudo apt-get purge libreoffice-common" and then re-ran the installation for the menus *.deb and all seems well. Thanks again for the tip and the help. Maybe help articles/postings should start including the purging of libreoffice-common from now on as well.